# Programmatically show Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using JavaScript. I don't know how to open bootstrap modal.
It works fine when I click on below button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="btnOpenPopup" data-target="#myModal">
     Open modal
 </button>
```

But I want to open it without user event, it should be opened programmatically.

I tried with `$("#btnOpenPopup").click();` and `(document.getElementById('btnOpenPopup')).click();` but it's not working.

Below is my modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your bootstrap version ?

Comment: 4.1.0 is my bootstrap version.

Comment: How and when do you use this function ? Is the page loaded ?

Comment: No I have a login button If login details is correct then I want to show this popup

Comment: Is there any console errors?

Comment: Please post your code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Its working for me.

If You have a login button and If login details is correct then You want to show this popup. Then do something like this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkUserDetails()"> Login</button>
```

Then In your script tag or your js file

```
function checkUserDetails() {
  // Check user details here 
  if (loginDetail) {  
    $("#YourModelName").show();   // show modal/popup
  } else {
    // do somethimg if logindetails is not valid
  }
}
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the modal() function inside document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Heres the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/12747/)

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a modal by using the `modal()` function.

`$("#myModal").modal(show | hide)`

This is the same for Bootstrap 3 and 4.

See source [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

Comment: @PranitaChavan Post your code you used when you tried this.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4.x it look like the good way is

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by `.hide()` and `.show()`

```
$(function(){
   $("#myModal").hide();
   $("#btnOpenPopup").click(function(){
         $("#myModal").show();
    });
 });
```